# Taking the derivative inside the integral sign of Jensen or Lindelöf's integral representations related to the alternating Zeta function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, dirichlet-series

Wikipedia's article for the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) tell us from the section *Integral representations* what is the representation due to Lindelöf, and what is the representation for $(s-1)\zeta(s)$ due to Jensen (I am saying the third and fourth paragraphs in the section).

> **Question.** I am interested in the domain $0<\Re s<1$, where $s$ is the complex variable. In some of previous identities, is justified the derivation with respect the complex variable $s$ inside the integral sign? Can you provide such example, the related calculations to get the derivation and what is a rigurous justification (using Jensen's representation or Lindelöf's representation or a closely variation of this kind of integrals, I am saying including a similar complex power of the factor $1/2+it$ in the integrand)? **Many thanks.**

Comment: Yes, because the integral converges (locally) uniformly. See any complex analysis course.  The basic example is for $Re(s) > 0, F(s) =  \int_0^\infty e^{-st}dt, F'(s) = -\int_0^\infty t e^{-st}dt$. And you are allowed to copy the formula you are mentioning.

Comment: Go on @user1952009 You've a lot of knowledges and it will very nice if you can provide a detailed example, For me and other students that want/need to know a detailed example.

Comment: Any case, many thanks @user1952009 I would like to encourage to you to write the answer with the integral representation for which you want teach us. To me it don't obvious.

Comment: Come back once you'll have read a complex analysis course...

Answer (score 0):

There is a derivation of $\displaystyle\eta(s) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{(1/2 + i t)^{-s}}{e^{\pi t}+e^{-\pi t}} \, dt$ (using the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem))

[Integral and Series Representations of Riemann's Zeta Function and Dirichlet's Eta Function and a Medley of Related Results](http://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/jmath/2013/181724.pdf)